# MySQL sanity check

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone please run a sanity check on the following query. We're trying to update our database to move 25000 random users to a new test email version (changing their emp_version to "0.6.3"). We want to only change users who currently have an active state of 1 and whose current emp_version is "0.6.2".

```
UPDATE email_users
SET emp_version="0.6.3" 
WHERE active = 1 
AND emp_version="0.6.2" 
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 25000;
```

Comment: Please let me know what exact error you faced in your query as syntax looks pretty good to me.

Comment: There was no error, it was just a sanity check to assure I wouldn't screw up a production database.

Comment: Don't mine but your code is completely fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Single Table Update**

You can use ORDER BY and LIMIT.
Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

```
UPDATE email_users
SET emp_version="0.6.3" 
WHERE active = 1 
AND emp_version="0.6.2" 
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 25000;
```

**Multi Table Update** (Using INNER JOIN)

In case of multi table update one can't use ORDER BY, LIMIT in UPDATE query, so as to use them we use subquery to get 25000 desired tuples and then do a INNER JOIN with same table. We can't update the subquery table as it really doesn't exist in database.

Try below query

```
UPDATE email_users eu INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT * FROM email_users 
      WHERE emp_version="0.6.2" 
      AND active = 1  
      ORDER BY rand() 
      LIMIT 25000) AS neu
SET eu.emp_version="0.6.3" 
WHERE eu.id = neu.id
```

Comment: It should read WHERE emp_version="0.6.2", but otherwise it worked great. Thanks!

Comment: I can't see the advantage of this query over the original. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Strawberry: You are right, that's why I have asked for the error he is getting in his code.

Comment: I see. Your answer seems to imply that this has been answered - perhaps in deleted comments!